# psycopg2 can't find table

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a Django rest framework API.

I'm trying to access some data from it using PostgreSQL and psycopg2.

```py
import psycopg2

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="*****",
                                  password='*****',
                                  host="127.0.0.1",
                                  port="5432",
                                  database="locations")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    postgreSQL_select_Query = "select * from KnownLocations"

    cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
    print("Selecting rows from find_second_gdt_points")
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    print(records)

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
    print("Error while fetching data from postgreSQL", error)

finally:
    # Closing connection
    if connection:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("Connection to DB is closed.")
```

When running the script I get the following error raised:

```
Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL relation "knownlocations" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from KnownLocations
```

But when printing the DB in the terminal the table does exist.

```
locations=# \dt

                     List of relations
 Schema |               Name               | Type  | Owner 
--------+----------------------------------+-------+-------
 public | KnownLocations                   | table | yovel
 public | auth_group                       | table | yovel
 public | auth_group_permissions           | table | yovel
 public | auth_permission                  | table | yovel
 public | auth_user                        | table | yovel
 public | auth_user_groups                 | table | yovel
 public | auth_user_user_permissions       | table | yovel
 public | authtoken_token                  | table | yovel
 public | django_admin_log                 | table | yovel
 public | django_content_type              | table | yovel
 public | django_migrations                | table | yovel
 public | django_session                   | table | yovel
 public | find_second_gdt_points           | table | yovel
 public | threelocationstrian_locationinfo | table | yovel
(14 rows)
```

Comment: try 'public'.'knownlocations'. see if it works

Comment: @aLuViAn raises the same error

Comment: Although the table is not totally in uppercase, all uppercase letters are cast to lowercase unless you out the name in double quotes. That's why it can't find the table

Comment: The answer was indeed  to use double quotes.

Comment: The correct answer is to name your tables using only lowercase :)